# CMD Which partition is active

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Is there any way to find out in a CMD script on which partition is Windows installed?
I need to make a program that makes a backup copy, but Windows is not always on `C:\`

I tried

```
C:\>DISKPART  
DISKPART>list volume



Volume      Bst  Bezeichnung   DS     Typ         Gr”áe    Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------   -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 1     C   XP_speziell   NTFS   Partition      9 GB  OK         Startpar
Volume 2     D   XP_allgemein  FAT32  Partition     28 GB  OK                 
Volume 3     E   DATEN         FAT32  Partition     28 GB  OK
```

but I need that as a one piece of code to make an IF out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo %systemdrive%` will give you the drive Windows is installed on. I'm not sure what you mean by "make an IF out of it", but if you want to test whether a given drive is the OS drive, you could do something like

```
if "%systemdrive%"=="C:" (
  [commands...]
)
```

BTW, "active partition" doesn't mean the same thing as the OS drive. That's the partition on which the boot sector is located, which points to the code to boot the OS, which may or may not be on the same drive.

Comment: do you know maybe how do I make a for loop instead of if? i have something like this: for /f %%A in ('%systemdrive% == %%A') do set OS_ROOT=%systemdrive%

Answer (score 1):

cd %windir%

[How to Determine Which Folder Windows Is Installed In](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305792/EN-US)

Comment: He's asking which drive, not which directory. Also, `cd` doesn't "find out" what a location is, it changes the current working directory to that location.